# How to use 1 Socket.IO connection on 2 Scene in Unity

Tags: sockets, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I created 2 Scene in Unity.

1st scene for Loading Screen ( its makes connection to SocketIO server viia Unity SOcket.IO)

2nd scene Main Screen.

I want to use same connection on  2nd scene.

Answer (score 0):

See [DontDestroyOnLoad()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html), use it to keep the SocketIO object when scene switch.

If you encounter more problems, you need to provide your code.

```
public class AddMeToTheGameobjectWithSocketIOComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) method as mentioned by @siusiulala, or you can utilize the [Singleton Pattern](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton). You'll have a slightly harder time getting the reference to the object from scene 2 by using `DontDestroyOnLoad`, compared to the singleton pattern.

With the singleton pattern, you would have a single object across all scenes that acts as your SocketIO wrapper. You can easily get the SocketIO reference by doing something like:

```cs
Socket socket = SocketIOSingleton.Instance;
```

Be aware that some developers will shy away from using the Singleton Pattern because it is frowned upon by some folks in the community and described as an anti-pattern, but I personally believe it works really well for games (especially ones made in Unity, where you don't really have access to pure dependency injection).